# How to use single pymongo connection pool for all aws lambda requests

Tags: python, mongodb, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, pymongo

I am using aws lambda functions and API Gateways together with python to serve HTTP requests.

Should I close pymongo connection after each request or is there a way to use common connection pool ?

If we use connection pool for each http request with 5 connections , Thousands request on lambda will open 5*1000=5000 mongodb connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it is not possible to transfer states between function invocations, but you can init your DB connection before the `event_handler` function and it will be reused for the next warm start of this specific function instance. If all requests start at the same time, you can limit the maximum number of instances at the same time to force a reuse of already started functions.

Here is a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html), that describes some best practices:

> Take advantage of execution environment reuse to improve the performance of
> your function. Initialize SDK clients and database connections outside
> of the function handler, and cache static assets locally in the /tmp
> directory. Subsequent invocations processed by the same instance of
> your function can reuse these resources. This saves cost by reducing
> function run time.